# How to include join column in json result with JPA+Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jackson, hibernate-onetomany

I have a `Province` class like below:

```
public class Province {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "province")
    List<City> cities;

}
```

and a `City` class like below:

```
public class City{
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    Province province;

}
```

now I want to have `pronivce_id` (as an int value not object) in JSON result of City in REST result.

How can I do this?

Comment: The way it was now is fine ,i guess better way could be select a province_id explicitly and set it into particular object getter setter you want to return. Also give us a service layer , so that we can see how you are returning.

Comment: JSON is nothing to do with JPA, so define where your problem is ... in performing a query and retrieving objects (JPA), or in converting the objects to JSON?

Comment: @parladneupane there is not any Service layer because I using Spring boot. I just return the `cityRepo.findAll()` that extends from `JPARepository` and in the result of my REST API I haven't `province_id`.

Comment: `@JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    Province province;` will always give you province object, so if you need City with province_id you need to have getter setter of province_id  in City class.

Answer (score 2):

You can return `province_id` with `JsonIdentityInfo` and `JsonIdentityReference` Jackson annotations.

```
public class City {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("province_id")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    Province province;

}
```

This issue is not related to Hibernate + JPA. All you need is to map `province` object correctly. But you will face some issues:
1) Lazy loading problem. To map all province ids you need to load them into memory. So you can't use `fetch = LAZY` and with incorrect mapping it will result with N+1 fetching problem.
2) This JSON mapping will apply to serialization and deserealization. So if you are going to use this entity not only as Query POJO (for JSON views etc), and also for Command objects (ex: for creation and update) - you will need pass province object as `id` field, not as an object.